# Microsoft Visual C++ 2019 (C) fatal error C1002

Tags: c, compiler-errors, visual-studio-2019

I have a auto-generated c-file with about 55MB. When I try to compile this file I get the error C1002 compiler is out of heap space in pass 2 from the Microsoft Visual C++ 2019 (C) compiler. When I watch the task manager during compiliation, I can watch how the memory runs out of free space. Is there any possibility to compile this file anyway? I have found some suggestions here to split the file into smaller ones but that's not really possible because the file is, like I stated at the beginning, auto-generated form an other program.

The file consists of the usual MATLAB-MEX entry functions (because it's auto-generated to be generated as mex).

```
static int mainfun_0(const casadi_real** arg, casadi_real** res, casadi_int* iw, casadi_real* w, int mem) {
  casadi_real a0, a1, a10, a100, a1000, a10000, a10001, a10002, a10003, a10004, a10005, a10006, a10007, a10008, a10009, a1001, a10010, a10011, a10012, a10013, a10014, a10015, a10016, a10017, a10018, a10019, a1002, a10020, a10021, a10022, a10023, a10024, ... , a9999;
  a0=-2.6950354609929081e+000;
  if (res[0]!=0) res[0][0]=a0;
  a1=-8.5106382978723416e-001;
  if (res[0]!=0) res[0][1]=a1;
  a2=2.8368794326241137e-001;
  if (res[0]!=0) res[0][2]=a2;
  a3=0.;
  if (res[0]!=0) res[0][3]=a3;
.
.
.
  a935=(a935+a936);
  a936=(a608*a774);
  a936=(a927-a936);
.
.
.
}
```

The generated code has 2 million lines and, as you can see in the variable list denoted with ..., I wasn't able to add all variables in this post because I ran out of characters.

Comment: Show the structure of that file.

Comment: The file has around 2 million lines, I don't really know how to show the structure properly. The main part of the file is a expression tree with lines like a130=(a7*a129);
  a131=(a130/a8);
  a131=fabs(a131);
and so on...

Comment: Show the whole file but cut the repeating lines and leave just 4-5 of them.

Comment: Are there 2 million different variables `annnn` where `nnnn` varies from 1 to 2000000, ore something like this?

Comment: It consists of the MATLAB-MEX entry funcions and a main function.

Comment: I tried to add a representative code snippet. That's how the variables are named (at least as far as I could figure it out). The variable with the highest number I could find is a35983, hence, there are around 36000 float variables

Comment: I think you'll still have to split it. If the file is automatically generated, then you must do it automatically via a script. Or add some more *RAM*. Or see if *Matlab* could spit the code in a nicer manner.